# Edit historical document, but keep version

Tags: document-library

My boss wants to be able to edit a previously approved version of a file, and then save it back with the original version number. As I understand SharePoint, it doesn't work that way! Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

To understand how version works you could check the following document, [Plan document versioning, content approval, and check-out controls in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx)

However if you want to update a previous version of a documenten you could use code like

```
foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in item.Versions){
  itemVersion.ListItem.File.CheckOut(SPFile.SPCheckOutType.Online, itemVersion.ListItem.File.TimeLastModified.ToString());
  itemVersion.ListItem["FieldName"] = "changed value here";
  itemVersion.ListItem.SystemUpdate(false)
  itemVersion.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Updated list item version", SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
}
```

Using the [sytemUpdate(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx) updates the database with changes that are made to the list item **without** changing the Modified or Modified By fields, or optionally, the **item version**.